# How do I edit search page on team site on SharePoint Online?

Tags: search, team-sites, refiner

Hello this search page from a team site. However when i search in HR it don't come up in the refinement sections. The documents have been tag by going to into term-store. I would like to how i can edit search page. there no option for me to edit page.

Comment: Did you check you have sufficient permission for this? If yes then you should be able to click Gear option from top right corner and click Edit Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only edit the pages in the Search Center (https://tenant.sharepoint.com/search) any "site search page" like the OSSSearchRestults.aspx page cannot be edited as it is a system page common to all tenants.